# adding column in a table disable features

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have downloaded a template in that there is an example of a table when i try to add a column in it some of it features are disabled like sorting, searching etc.

```
  <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header">
          <h3 class="box-title">Data Table With Full Features</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-header -->
        <div class="box-body">
          <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Rendering engine</th>
              <th>Browser</th>
              <th>Platform(s)</th>
              <th>Engine version</th>
              <th>CSS grade</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Trident</td>
              <td>Internet
                Explorer 5.0
              </td>
              <td>Win 95+</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>C</td>
            </tr></tbody>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <th>Rendering engine</th>
              <th>Browser</th>
              <th>Platform(s)</th>
              <th>Engine version</th>
              <th>CSS grade</th>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-body -->
      </div>
```

Comment: How are you adding column? All you have shown us is basic html that has no built in support for sort or search. Please provide a [mcve]